# Download all R zip packages from webpage

Tags: r

The organization I currently work for blocks the CRAN Repository in R Studio. So in order to install packages I need to go to http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/ and manually download each one and their dependencies and install them in RStudio. It gets quite tedious.

Is there a way for me download all of the zip files on this page at once and put them in a folder on my desktop? And then from there is there a code to install/load all the zip file packages at once in RStudio?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try using the Microsoft CRAN mirror at https://cran.microsoft.com. Most orgs won't block a Microsoft URL

Comment: That looks like about 13.8GB of downloads and 17,378 zip files.

Comment: Hi! So how do I change where R installs packages? Like from CRAN to cran.microsoft.com? Sorry I’m fairly new to R and haven't quite learned how to do everything!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible example using the package *rvest*. The *rvest* functions are used to get the list of packages to be downloaded.

Note that the `Sys.sleep(1L)` call pauses the execution for one second between downloads. You can obviously change that or remove it altogether.

```r
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6'

packages <- rvest::read_html(url) %>%
  rvest::html_nodes("a") %>%
  rvest::html_text() %>%
  grep('.zip$', ., value = TRUE) %>%
  sort()

for (pkg in packages) {
  Sys.sleep(1L)
  cat('Downloading', pkg, '...')
  pkg_url <- file.path(url, pkg)
  download.file(pkg_url, destfile = pkg, quiet = TRUE)  
  cat(' DONE.\n')
}
```